# How to Profile a certain function in Python

Tags: python, psutil

I have written a command line based application and want to profile every module when it runs. It is a single threaded application , and the modules are function calls which do something. I need to measure things like **Time taken** by the function, **average cpu usage** by the function, **average memory usage** by the function.
I am able to measure the time taken by measuring system time and before and after call.(or using cprofile)
But I can't figure out anything which would give me the other data properly.
I have read about the resource module which comes inbuilt in python but I want the application to be cross-platform (windows & linux) and resource module is not present in linux.
I was thinking about using **psutil** , but reading the docs , i don't think it provides what i want. Like if I call process.cpu_percent() before and after function call, would it give cpu usage by the function(difference in cpu usage between two cpu percent calls) or cpu usage at that point of time. The memory percent seems a bit ambiguous .

How do i measure what i want using psutil? or can i using psutil? or is there a better module available fit for what i want?

Comment: Have you considered the [profile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) (or cProfile) module? Alternatively there is also [line_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler/)

Comment: Yes, i have considered cProfile. But the problem is that it only measures the time taken by a function(and no. of recursive calls). I need to measure CPU usage & memory usage by the function as well

Comment: My main motive is to provide some statistics to users(& also me - to analyze), because the program might take a while to run. If the input data is large. I don't need in-depth analysis though. Something like what we see in windows task managers' processes tab. Where there is a CPU usage , & Private working set(memory usage)